# Avoiding pointers when calling the function call operator of the derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, functor

I have a question regarding inheritance with function objects.

I guess this must have been asked a gazzilion times here on Stack Overflow but the sheer number of questions with similar wording makes it near-impossible for me to find anything.

Suppose I have a base abstract class:

```
class BinaryOperation
{
public:
    virtual int operator()(int a, int b) = 0;
};
```

From which two new classes are derived:

```
class Plus : public BinaryOperation
{
public:
    virtual int operator()(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    };
};

class Minus : public BinaryOperation
{
public:
    virtual int operator()(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    };
};
```

I would like to use `std::map` to map strings to various functors that are derived from the same class:

My first approach was

```
std::map<std::string, BinaryOperation> operator_map;
operator_map["+"] = Plus();
operator_map["-"] = Minus();

operator_map["-"](5, 2);
```

Obviously this didn't work because we cannot instantiate an abstract class.

If I use a pointer to the base class, it works just fine but that looks clumsier and since we have to `new` the objects that makes it more prone to memory leaks (we have to manually `delete` the objects)

```
std::map<std::string, BinaryOperation*> operator_map;

operator_map["+"] = new Plus();
operator_map["-"] = new Minus(); 

std::cout << (*operator_map["-"])(5, 2)
```

What would be the preferred way of achieving this functionality without sacrificing the benefits of RAII?

Comment: You don't have to worry about pointers too much when you use smart pointers ;)

Comment: Well, I know, I use them extensively. I just hope they are not required for something apparently so simple :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make a map of `std::string` to `std::function<int(int, int)>`. This allows you to do away with any common base classes, since the function objects provide the polimorphism:

```
struct Plus {
  int operator()(int a, int b) const{ return a+b; }
};

struct Minus {
  int operator()(int a, int b) const{ return a-b; }
};

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, std::function<int(int,int)>> opMap;
  using namespace std::placeholders;

  opMap["-"] = Minus();
  opMap["+"] = Plus();

  std::cout << opMap["-"](5,2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << opMap["+"](5,6) << std::endl;
}
```

Note that the standard library provides functors that implement arithmetic operations in the [`functional` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional), so you don't have to implement `Minus` and `Plus` yourself:

```
opMap["-"] = std::minus<int>();
opMap["+"] = std::plus<int>();
```

Comment: OK, I tried it and it works. When I have it defined like this, what do I do with the base class?

Comment: @Tibor, you can just forget about the base class completely, remove it from your design, unless you need it for something else.